# Multiple words in Where field LIKE

Tags: python, sql, string, sql-like, ssms-2014

I have a list of values (words) and I want to check if a column in my table contains a value (any value) from the list.

My list can be very long so I want to create it using a for loop, for example:

```
words = ( 'one', 'two', 'three' )
whereClause=""
a=""
for word in words:
   temp=" item LIKE '%" +word +  " %' or"
   whereClause=whereClause+temp
whereClause = whereClause[17:]  #delete first "item LIKE"
whereClause = whereClause[:-3] #delete last "or"
```

Now I want to put it in my sql query:

```
sql= """select name
from table
where item LIKE ? """

cursor.execute(sql, whereClause)
rows=cursor.fetchall()
```

It's not working, any suggestions?

Do you think I better get all the values of the column "name" using *sql query* and only then check if values from the list exists using *Python*?
Thanks!

Comment: your problem is when you remove your first item like. Simplify things and in your sql variable leave it as 'where ?' and dont remove the first item like

Comment: Please avoid constructing your `where` clause this way as it exposes you to `SQL injection` attacks. Your best bet is to construct as many `OR item LIKE ?` iterations as the number of elements in `words`. Then pass in the whole `words` array as a sqlParameter at execution time.

Comment: thanks @Stavr00 , but I'm not sure I understand your idea. could you please explain?

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel I tried it and got an error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are still facing issues:

```
words = ( 'one', 'two', 'three' )
whereClause=""

i = 1
for word in words:
    if i == 1:
        whereClause = " item LIKE '%" +word + "%'"
    else:
        whereClause += " OR item LIKE '%" +word + "%'"
    i += 1

sql= """select name
from table
where {0} """.format(whereClause)

cursor.execute(sql)
rows=cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very fluent in Python but here goes:

```
for word in words:
   whereClause += " OR" if whereClause
   whereClause += " ITEM LIKE ?"
sql= "select name from table where" + whereClause
cursor.execute(sql, words)
```